# Resize image and know previous and resized points

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I know that `imresize` in MATLAB will resize image `I1` to `I2` with a scale. Is there a way to know the association between pixels in the original image and the resized image? E.g., is there some mapping that exists?

On top of all, please consider performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the simplest way is just to multiply by the scale factor (or divide to find previous coordinates):

```
% read image and generate several coordinates to plot on
im = imread('lena.jpg');
[x,y] = meshgrid(100:100:450);
x = x(:); y = y(:);
% scale of resizing
scale = 0.4;
% plot original image
subplot(131);
imshow(im);
hold on;
plot(x,y,'xr','LineWidth',2,'MarkerSize',15);
title(sprintf('Original, size = [%d,%d]',size(im,1),size(im,2)));
% resize to obtain smaller image
imSmall = imresize(im,scale);
subplot(132);
imshow(imSmall);
hold on;
% plot scaled coordinates
plot(x.*scale,y.*scale,'xr','LineWidth',2,'MarkerSize',15);
title(sprintf('Small, size = [%d,%d]',size(imSmall,1),size(imSmall,2)));
% resize to obtain larger image
imBig = imresize(im,1/scale);
subplot(133);
imshow(imBig);
hold on;
% plot scaled coordinates
plot(x./scale,y./scale,'xr','LineWidth',2,'MarkerSize',15);
title(sprintf('Big, size = [%d,%d]',size(imBig,1),size(imBig,2)));
```

[image]